# Can't boot Ubuntu 12.10 from USB HELP?

Tags: installation, 12.10, boot

I can't boot ubuntu from Usb flash driver (8Gb) from Windows xp .. Is there any Autoboot or something like that . Can you answer that now cause My Pc is messed up with virus i want to install that now

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may want to include your pc's brand and specifications, I'd suspect you need to change boot order to boot into the USB at startup but it's different for each PC brand so you'll have to give us more information so that we can help you out :)

Answer (score 3):

First you need to prepare the USB using any tool like [Linux Live USB creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) or [Unversal USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).

Then You need to open BIOS to configure boot order and choose USB disk as first bootable driver to boot from it.

BIOS generally opens with speical key like F2 / DEL. At is also shown in the splash screen of BIOS if available.